# How can I escape invalid Mongo field name characters with a Jackson ObjectMapper?

Tags: json, mongodb, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to parse a JSON string to `JsonNode`, which I then write to Mongo. That works fine, except for cases where there is an invalid character (`.` or `$`) in a field name.

To fix this I could use Mongo 3.6+, but the docs discourage this, mentioning that even though `.` and `$` are now allowed in field names, querying may still be tricky. Therefore I would like to escape these characters when parsing JSON.

How can I escape `.` and `$` when parsing JSON using Jackson?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom delegating `JsonParser`, which can be supplied through a `JsonFactory.`

For example:

```java
new ObjectMapper(new MongoInvalidCharacterEscapingJsonFactory());
```

```java
public class MongoInvalidCharacterEscapingJsonFactory extends JsonFactory {    @Override
    protected JsonParser _createParser(char[] aData, int anOffset, int aLength, IOContext aContext, boolean anIsRecyclable) throws IOException {
        return new MongoInvalidCharacterEscapingParser(super._createParser(aData, anOffset, aLength, aContext, anIsRecyclable));
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonParser _createParser(Reader aReader, IOContext aContext) throws IOException {
        return new MongoInvalidCharacterEscapingParser(super._createParser(aReader, aContext));
    }
}
```

```java
class MongoInvalidCharacterEscapingParser extends JsonParserDelegate {
    MongoInvalidCharacterEscapingParser(JsonParser aMommy) {
        super(aMommy);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentName() throws IOException {
        if (hasTokenId(JsonTokenId.ID_FIELD_NAME)) {
            return delegate.getCurrentName().replaceAll("\\.", "REPLACEMENTFORPERIOD").replaceAll("\\$", "REPLACEMENTFORDOLLARSIGN");
        }

        return delegate.getCurrentName();
    }
}
```

All imports from `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` and `java.io`.